# when I set text in android textview it show #039;

Tags: java, android, textview

When I set a json string from web service call and it has a £ sign it shows `pound;`, `yen;`, and if it has an apostrophe( ' ) it shows `&#039;`

UPDATED: 
json = `Empresszulu$£¥€©™` sets as `Empresszulu$&pound;&yen;&copy;&trade`, and 
`don't` sets as `don#039;t`.
NOTE: the json is from mysql so it could be changed to anything anytime.

Comment: Please add your code and part of json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "UTF-8" encoding for using this kind of special character.
You have to encode for your expected character like this way :

```
 String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), android.httpclient.protocol.HTTP.UTF_8);
 JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
```